# Gnuplot - pdfcairo

Tags: terminal, debian, gnuplot

I'm trying to set my terminal to pdf output, using the line

```
gnuplot> set terminal pdfcairo enhanced
```

but what I get is:

```
unknown or ambiguous terminal type;
```

So, I tried installing the libraries using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev 
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev
```

And in return:

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
O pacote libcairo2-dev não está disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote.
Isto pode significar que o pacote está faltando, ficou obsoleto ou
está disponível somente a partir de outra fonte

E: O pacote 'libcairo2-dev' não tem candidato para instalação
```

Which basically means "reading the package list, a package is missing, referenced by another package, error, has no installation candidate, bla bla...".

I don't know how to fix this. Please, help a noob (yet) debian user.

Comment: This is not really a gnuplot related issue but rather debian, so you might be better off to ask in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). It seems that your are missing a source containing these packages (or they are outdated), see e.g. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296488/e-package-any-package-has-no-installation-candidate) for some related suggestions.